# How to create a mimic of the Keynote for iPad sidebar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, keynote

I am looking to create a representation of the sidebar shown in [Keynote for iPad](http://www.apple.com/uk/apps/keynote/). How can I do this for iOS? I would imagine that a UITableView is needed, but not quite sure on the saving of the current screen?

Already seen one example project , but wasn't too much help

Comment: What You exactly want please clarify your question?

Comment: I just want the sidebar which allows you to switch between different slides in the presentation

Comment: ok Show you one link check you want like that only.

Answer (score 0):

use this link I think this will helpful for you.first try with this code.
You will try this code add one scrollview on nib and set its contentsize on viewdidload

```
CGFloat x = 20;
for (int i = 0;i<[playerScores count];i++) {
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 10, 60, 60)];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[playerScores objectAtIndex:i]];
[view setText:text];

[yardsScrollView addSubview:view];
[myLabel release];
x = x+125;
}
```

PlayersScore is a NSMutable array which have many text like how much view You want.

then also check this.

https://github.com/bjhomer/HSImageSidebarView